# Values not showing up during debugging in eclipse PDT

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I am trying to debug this simplepie.inc (called from index.php )which is dumping me with error during parsing one of the feed.

After stepping through the line `$utf8_data = 'UTF-8';` which I hardcoded in to test things out, the value of the variable remains `<Uninitialized>` as shown in the screenshot below.

Why is that so?

Variables and values are showing up nicely if I am stepping through the debug in index.php thou.

[alt text http://a.imageshack.us/img713/486/14jul10105825pm.jpg](http://a.imageshack.us/img713/486/14jul10105825pm.jpg)

Comment: Can you post more details?  Debugger type (XDebug vs Zend Debugger)? Debugger version?  PHP version?

EDIT: Ah, tagged XDebug - other questions still apply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an existing bug in the 2.0.x branch of XDebug with PHP 5.3 which prevents local variables from being visible.  I would recommend updating/building either the latest version from SVN, or using a recent 2.1.x release, even if in RC/Beta status.

More information available here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=158396

Comment: Thanks drowe, this is really the case for me it seems :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has bugged me for almost a year. Actually we had to set up virtual machines with ubuntu because we did not get xdebug to work on windows.

I just downloaded XAMPP 1.7.7 from www.apachefriends.org and it seams that this bug has been fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveState provides precompiled versions of Xdebug for most operating systems. Package can be downloaded from this page;

http://code.activestate.com/komodo/remotedebugging/

Look for "PHP Remote Debugging Client" and download for your OS.

If you choose this option, take the xdebug.so from the appropriate PHP version directory and use it.

If you're updating a XAMMP for Mac install, it's in the XAMMP folder.

xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so

Snagged from here:

http://kubyshkin.ru/posts/installing-php-xdebug-extension-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion.html